# Field '__jmpbuf' could not be resolved -cpp

Tags: c++

I get this error when trying to compile my program:

```
Field '__jmpbuf' could not be resolved
```

I looked for a solution for hours and can't seem to find out where is the culprit.

The `Thread.h` file contains the header of the class. It has the private member:

```
sigjmp_buf _env;
```

And the implementation is inside Thread.cpp:

```
#include "Thread.h"
#include <setjmp.h>
#include "translateAdd.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define COUNTER_INIT -1

int Thread::_idCounter = COUNTER_INIT;

Thread::Thread(void (*threadsFunc)(void))
: threadsFunction(threadsFunc), _stack(new char[STACK_SIZE]), _quantums(1)
{
      address_t sp, pc;

      sp = (address_t)_stack + STACK_SIZE - sizeof(address_t);
      pc = (address_t)threadsFunc;
      // set environment for later return
      sigsetjmp(_env, 1);
      (_env->__jmpbuf)[JB_SP] = translate_address(sp);
      (_env->__jmpbuf)[JB_PC] = translate_address(pc);
      sigemptyset(&_env->__saved_mask);

    _id = ++_idCounter;

    _state = READY;

}
```

**EDIT**: Using eclipse as the IDE under ubuntu 32bit

EDIT: Another complete example that doesn't compile on my machine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define SECOND 1000000
#define STACK_SIZE 4096

char stack1[STACK_SIZE];
char stack2[STACK_SIZE];

sigjmp_buf env[2];

#ifdef __x86_64__
/* code for 64 bit Intel arch */

typedef unsigned long address_t;
#define JB_SP 6
#define JB_PC 7

/* A translation is required when using an address of a variable.
   Use this as a black box in your code. */
address_t translate_address(address_t addr)
{
    address_t ret;
    asm volatile("xor    %%fs:0x30,%0\n"
        "rol    $0x11,%0\n"
                 : "=g" (ret)
                 : "0" (addr));
    return ret;
}

#else
/* code for 32 bit Intel arch */

typedef unsigned int address_t;
#define JB_SP 4
#define JB_PC 5 

/* A translation is required when using an address of a variable.
   Use this as a black box in your code. */
address_t translate_address(address_t addr)
{
    address_t ret;
    asm volatile("xor    %%gs:0x18,%0\n"
        "rol    $0x9,%0\n"
                 : "=g" (ret)
                 : "0" (addr));
    return ret;
}

#endif

void switchThreads(void)
{
  static int currentThread = 0;

  int ret_val = sigsetjmp(env[currentThread],1);
  printf("SWITCH: ret_val=%d\n", ret_val); 
  if (ret_val == 1) {
      return;
  }
  currentThread = 1 - currentThread;
  siglongjmp(env[currentThread],1);
}

void f(void)
{
  int i = 0;
  while(1){
    ++i;
    printf("in f (%d)\n",i);
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
      printf("f: switching\n");
      switchThreads();
    }
    usleep(SECOND);
  }
}

void g(void)
{
  int i = 0;
  while(1){
    ++i;
    printf("in g (%d)\n",i);
    if (i % 5 == 0) {
      printf("g: switching\n");
      switchThreads();
    }
    usleep(SECOND);
  }
}

void setup(void)
{
  address_t sp, pc;

  sp = (address_t)stack1 + STACK_SIZE - sizeof(address_t);
  pc = (address_t)f;
  sigsetjmp(env[0], 1);
  (env[0]->__jmpbuf)[JB_SP] = translate_address(sp);
  (env[0]->__jmpbuf)[JB_PC] = translate_address(pc);
  sigemptyset(&env[0]->__saved_mask);     

  sp = (address_t)stack2 + STACK_SIZE - sizeof(address_t);
  pc = (address_t)g;
  sigsetjmp(env[1], 1);
  (env[1]->__jmpbuf)[JB_SP] = translate_address(sp);
  (env[1]->__jmpbuf)[JB_PC] = translate_address(pc);
  sigemptyset(&env[1]->__saved_mask);         
}

int main(void)
{
  setup();      
  siglongjmp(env[0], 1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `sigjmp_buf` type is unspecified. You can and should not use it as a structure pointer.

Comment: `sigjmp_buf` is normally defined as an array. This code (not your code I'm guessing) seems to think it should be defined as something else.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg we were told to use it. I've added a complete example of code that should work if you can please take a look

Comment: @john I added another example that uses an array. Still doesn't compile

Comment: It doesn't compile because you can't use fields inside it. You don't even know if it's a pointer (in which case you use it without making it point to anything) much less a structure with fields. It's an opaque box whose contents you know nothing about.

Comment: _But_ if you need to, then check the types properly first! On my system it's `typedef struct __jmp_buf_tag jmp_buf[1]`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg it's safe to say that I'm lost with this one. It's a part of an assignment. Tried to add your code with no success

Comment: @Tom You've been given some code which doesn't work for some reason. From what I know there's no reason to think that it should work. I think you are just going to have to go back to the person who gave you the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to use the internal fields (which will only be valid for your compiler on your system) you need to check the types:

```
typedef struct __jmp_buf_tag sigjmp_buf[1];
```

That means that `sigjmp_buf` is not a pointer, but an array with a single structure in it. So you use it like a normal array of structures:

```
sigjmp_buf _env;

_env[0].__jmpbuf[x] = y;
```

I really recommend against the use the internal field of this structure. Linux have other functions to simplify cooperative threading (which is what you seem to be implementing).